# how to add different layer when i click a button

Tags: android, layer

i have 4 imageButton ,
when i click in one of this button a layer should appear over a imageView that i created.

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()){

    case R.id.categoriaA1:

        // add layer a1
        break;

    case R.id.categoriaA2:
        // add layer a2
        break;
    case R.id.categoriaA3:
        //add  layer A3
        break;
    case R.id.categoriaA4:
        // add layer A4
        break;
```

myAvatar is my ImageView.
can someone help me?

EDIT this is my xml code ( i have 20 imageButton in 4 categories)

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:columnCount="1"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.settingavatar.MyAvatar" >

<!-- problemi con il dimensionamento -->

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/anteprimaAvatar"
    android:layout_width="282dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp" 

    android:background="@drawable/btn_background"/>
<!-- griglia che contiene le 4 categorie per i vari oggetti che si possono aggiungere all'avatar -->

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/anteprimaAvatar"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- sottogriglia per la categoria A -->

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/categoriaA1"
            android:layout_width="34dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cata1"
            android:tag="accessorio" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/categoriaA2"
            android:layout_width="34dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cata2"
            android:tag="accessorio" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/categoriaA3"
            android:layout_width="34dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cata3"
            android:tag="accessorio" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/categoriaA4"
            android:layout_width="34dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cata4"
            android:tag="accessorio" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/categoriaA5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:tag="accessorio" />
    </GridLayout>

    <!-- sottogriglia per la categoria B -->

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/categoriaB1"
            android:layout_width="34dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:background="@drawable/catb1"
            android:tag="accessorio" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/categoriaB2"
            android:layout_width="34dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:background="@drawable/catb2"
            android:tag="accessorio" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/categoriaB3"
            android:layout_width="34dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:background="@drawable/catb3"
            android:tag="accessorio" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/categoriaB4"
            android:layout_width="34dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:background="@drawable/catb4"
            android:tag="accessorio" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/categoriaB5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:tag="accessorio" />
    </GridLayout>

    <!-- sottogriglia per la categoria C -->

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/categoriaC1"
            android:layout_width="34dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:background="@drawable/catc1"
            android:tag="accessorio" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/categoriaC2"
            android:layout_width="34dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:background="@drawable/catc2"
            android:tag="accessorio" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/categoriaC3"
            android:layout_width="34dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:background="@drawable/catc3"
            android:tag="accessorio" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/categoriaC4"
            android:layout_width="34dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:background="@drawable/catc4"
            android:tag="accessorio" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/categoriaC5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:tag="accessorio" />
    </GridLayout>

    <!-- sottogriglia per la categoria D -->

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/categoriaD1"
            android:layout_width="34dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:background="@drawable/catd1"
            android:tag="accessorio" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/categoriaD2"
            android:layout_width="34dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:background="@drawable/catd2"
            android:tag="accessorio" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/categoriaD3"
            android:layout_width="34dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:background="@drawable/catd3"
            android:tag="accessorio" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/categoriaD4"
            android:layout_width="34dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:background="@drawable/catd4"
            android:tag="accessorio" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/categoriaD5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:tag="accessorio" />
    </GridLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: what do you mean by layer? a layout or what? you can change the image view as the other guy suggested or you can hide/show the layout over your image view if this is what you want to do

Comment: i'm trying to do your second option, but i dont know how.

Comment: it can easily be done by making a layout over your image view and hide it, and on button click set the visibility of that layout to View.VISIBLE, if you are still confused post your xml so i can help you with the code :)

Comment: see the recent answer posted, you can do something like that to solve your problem. Only the LinearLayout or what ever layout you use should be of same size as the image view, hope it helps :)

Comment: see the answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use visibility action with layouts

For Example

```
        LinearLayout lly1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lly1);
        LinearLayout lly2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lly1);
        LinearLayout lly3 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lly1);
        LinearLayout lly4 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lly1);


  public void onClick(View v) {

switch(v.getId()){

case R.id.categoriaA1:

    // add layer a1
   lly1.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
   lly2.setVisibility(v.GONE);
   lly3.setVisibility(v.GONE);
   lly4.setVisibility(v.GONE);
    break;

case R.id.categoriaA2:
    // add layer a2
   lly2.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
   lly1.setVisibility(v.GONE);
   lly3.setVisibility(v.GONE);
   lly4.setVisibility(v.GONE);
    break;
case R.id.categoriaA3:
    //add  layer A3
   lly3.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
   lly2.setVisibility(v.GONE);
   lly1.setVisibility(v.GONE);
   lly4.setVisibility(v.GONE);
    break;
case R.id.categoriaA4:
    // add layer A4
   lly4.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
   lly2.setVisibility(v.GONE);
   lly3.setVisibility(v.GONE);
   lly1.setVisibility(v.GONE);

    break;
```

}

Where coming to layout activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lly1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lly2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lly3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lly4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change source or background of your target imageView when clicked. 
For example

```
ImageView imageview = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.categoriaA1);
imageview.setBackground(Drawable your_background);
```

Comment: but i wont replace the imageView, but add a new layer in my image

Comment: so you replace layout, not imageView

Answer (score 0):

```
  <GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:columnCount="1"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context="com.example.settingavatar.MyAvatar" >



  <ImageView
android:id="@+id/anteprimaAvatar"
android:layout_width="282dp"
android:layout_height="150dp" 
android:background="@drawable/btn_background"/>

<LinearLayout 
 android:id="@+id/anteprimaAvatarLinear"
 android:layout_width="282dp"
 android:visibility="gone"
 android:layout_height="150dp"></LinearLayout>

<GridLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/anteprimaAvatar"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- sottogriglia per la categoria A -->

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/categoriaA1"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cata1"
        android:tag="accessorio" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/categoriaA2"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cata2"
        android:tag="accessorio" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/categoriaA3"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cata3"
        android:tag="accessorio" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/categoriaA4"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cata4"
        android:tag="accessorio" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/categoriaA5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:tag="accessorio" />
</GridLayout>

<!-- sottogriglia per la categoria B -->

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/categoriaB1"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:background="@drawable/catb1"
        android:tag="accessorio" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/categoriaB2"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:background="@drawable/catb2"
        android:tag="accessorio" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/categoriaB3"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:background="@drawable/catb3"
        android:tag="accessorio" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/categoriaB4"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:background="@drawable/catb4"
        android:tag="accessorio" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/categoriaB5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:tag="accessorio" />
</GridLayout>

<!-- sottogriglia per la categoria C -->

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/categoriaC1"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:background="@drawable/catc1"
        android:tag="accessorio" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/categoriaC2"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:background="@drawable/catc2"
        android:tag="accessorio" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/categoriaC3"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:background="@drawable/catc3"
        android:tag="accessorio" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/categoriaC4"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:background="@drawable/catc4"
        android:tag="accessorio" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/categoriaC5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:tag="accessorio" />
</GridLayout>

<!-- sottogriglia per la categoria D -->

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/categoriaD1"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:background="@drawable/catd1"
        android:tag="accessorio" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/categoriaD2"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:background="@drawable/catd2"
        android:tag="accessorio" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/categoriaD3"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:background="@drawable/catd3"
        android:tag="accessorio" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/categoriaD4"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:background="@drawable/catd4"
        android:tag="accessorio" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/categoriaD5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:tag="accessorio" />
</GridLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

and in JAVA code do this against the button click:

```
 LinearLayout anteprimaAvatarLinear= (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.anteprimaAvatarLinear);
 ImageView anteprimaAvatar= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.anteprimaAvatar);
 anteprimaAvatarLinear.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE); 
 anteprimaAvatar..setVisibility(v.GONE);  // OR INVISIBLE
```